# Promoted Links using mailto to open Outlook 2016 + Insert Text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, promoted-links

The string below opens Outlook 2016 and insert items of text

```
mailto:it.servicedesk@testsite.com&subject=Insight%20professional/keyworker%20code%20request&body=Insight%20professional%20code%20request%0A%0AName%20of%20person%20who%20needs%20a%20code%20(write%20'self'%20if%20it's%20you!):%0A%0AName%20of%20line%20manager:%0A%0AMain%20Team%20or%20Service%20(or%20Bank/Flexi):%0A%0AProfessional%20role:%0A%0ATeam%20service%20for%20which%20the%20code%20is%20needed
```

When I insert the above text in the Promoted Links - **Link Location** column and then select **Verify** the code opens Outlook 2016 and inserts the text perfectly.

**Problem**
When I select OK to save the above text it comes up with a red exclamation mark.

> "Message you need to fix some problems before we can save your changes"

Any suggestions on what is happening and a likely fix, please?

I appreciate any assistance to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Link Location has a length limit. You could try to shorten the url.
[image]

In addition, we should use ‘?’ to connect mail address and subject.

Sample url:`"mailto:it.servicedesk@testsite.com?subject=Insight%20professional/keyworker%20code%20request&body=Insight%20professional”`.